# Iteration and array

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

How do I iterate 9 times and produce three arrays like this:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
["a","b","c"]

4 d
5 e
6 f
["d","e","f"]

7 g
8 h
9 i
["g","h","i"]  ?
-------------------------------------
1.upto(9) do
 xxx = gets.chomp
  wn << xxx
if wn.length ==3
puts wn.inspect

end
end
------------------------------------
```

I get the following output:

```
a
b
c
["a", "b", "c"]
d
e
f
g
h
i
```

Not the results I hoped for :(

Comment: You haven't specified the language you're using (Ruby perhaps?), but you probably want to use `if wn.length % 3 == 0`.

Comment: Please, add the tag of the programming language you are using, to gain attention from experts of that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
a1 = []
a2 = []
a3 = []
1.upto(9) do |i|
  if a1.empty? || a1.size < 3
    a1 << gets.chomp!
  elsif a2.size < 3 
    a2 << gets.chomp!
  else
    a3 << gets.chomp!
  end
end
puts a1
puts a2
puts a3
```

Create the 3 arrays, iterate 9 times, create conditions to populate them.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to iterate? you could always break your string by length, like so:

```
"abcdefghi".scan(/.{3}/).map{|i| i.split('')} # => [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]
```

If you really must iterate:

```
1.upto(9) do
 xxx = gets.chomp
 wn << xxx
 if wn.length % 3 == 0 
   puts wn.inspect
  end
end
```

Comment: That first one could be made simpler: `"abcdefghi".chars.each_slice(3).to_a`

Answer (score 0):

I think nested loops are a clean solution for you.

```
a = [[],[],[]]
3.times do |i|
  3.times { |j| a[i][j] = gets.strip }
  puts a[i].inspect
end
```